# How to implement basic authentication on github pages created by slate

Tags: authentication, github-pages

I created a documentation site by using [slate](https://github.com/lord/slate), then deployed it on Github pages. However it became public because Github pages are public. I am wondering if there is a way to add a basic authentication on this github page? So only the team can see the documentation.

Any suggestions/hints would be appreciated!

Comment: https://blog.termian.dev/posts/static-site-auth/

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't. Github pages provide basic static hosting. That is all. There are no (server side) dynamic options at all.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I know Github does not have it. However, you can add a basic auth by yourself, just like this one:https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-auth for jekyll. I was just wondering if I could do the similar to slate, but I don't have a clue how to start, that is why i am asking. Does it make sense?

Comment: @Lisa — The solution jekyll-auth uses is "Don't use GitHub Pages for hosting"